# Send jQuery array to MVC 4 Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have been searching for a way to do this, and I have looked at the several questions posted on here, but I can't obtain all elements of the array I want.  Here is the array I'm sending:

```
function myFunction(e) {

        var containerChildren = $("#active").children();

        for (i = 0; i < containerChildren.length; i++) {
            var announcementarray = new Array();
            announcementarray[i] = $('#' + containerChildren[i].id).data("id");
            alert(announcementarray[i]);
        }


        $.ajax({
            data:
                {
                    activeid: announcementarray
                },
            datatype: 'json',
            url: '/HumanResources/Announcement/AnnouncementActive',
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            traditional: true,
            error: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            success: function (result) {
                //alert(result);
            }
        });
    }
```

However, whenever the controller receives this data, it only shows the last children with the an actual value, all the others are `undefined` .  Here is the declaration of my controller

```
public ActionResult AnnouncementActive(string[] activeid, string[] inactiveid)
{
}
```

Any help is appreciated!  (I have tried `traditional: true`, `.serialize()`, etc)

Comment: Found mistake: declaration of array is inside for loop.  After taking it out of there, problem fixed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are recreating your array for each child element in your first selector.
Try something like this:

```
function myFunction(e) {

    var announcementarray = [];

    $("#active").children().each(function() {
        announcementarray.push($(this).data("id"));
    });

    $.ajax({
        data:
            {
                activeid: announcementarray
            },
        datatype: 'json',
        url: '/HumanResources/Announcement/AnnouncementActive',
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        traditional: true,
        error: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            //alert(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The elements returned from $.children(); are also jQuery objects so this could be made a little better. See my updates.

Comment: That does seem a lot less confusing. Thanks for clearing it up. However, whenever I run it, I get a runtime error saying it does not recognize 'data' (which is a property in the html 'data-*'

Comment: I'll mark your response as the answer but I found my error.  I had my declaration of the array inside of the for loop. After taking it out, it works like a charm!! Thanks for your feedback!